# delay time of the lockscreen 'GDM3 Ubuntu 18.04'

Tags: lock-screen, gdm

How can I set the delay time of the lockscreen 'GDM3 Ubuntu 18.04' before it turns black. The problem is that when I press WIN + L, my lockscreen turns on, and for almost 1 second I see the clock and date in the center of the screen. Then the screen disappears to black. But I want to see this watch all the time, I just can not move the mouse constantly when I want to see the time. Please help set the delay time!